# MacOSX swift NSLayoutContraint Resizes Wrong Object

Tags: xcode, swift

I programmatically add a button to an NSWindow's content view and when I add a constraint to center it, the button is not moved and instead the window is made smaller:

[Here is a picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GybsX.png)

```
    windowN=NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect((NSScreen.mainScreen()!.visibleFrame.width/2)-100, (NSScreen.mainScreen()!.visibleFrame.height/2)-100, 200, 200), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, `defer`: false, screen: NSScreen.mainScreen())

    windowN.releasedWhenClosed=false
    windowN.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    windowN.title="Title"
    windowN.minSize=NSSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    let s=NSStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    windowN.contentView?=(s.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Me") as! NSViewController).view
    var view=windowN.contentView!
    button=NSButton(frame: NSMakeRect(0,0,100,30))
    button.setButtonType(NSButtonType.MomentaryPushInButton)
    button.bezelStyle=NSBezelStyle.RoundedBezelStyle


    button.title="Hello"

    view.addSubview(button)
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    windowN.delegate=self
```

No errors are thrown.

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like you set the `view` to the center for `button`, try to swap them in `view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(...))` and try to make `windowN.minSize=NSSize` more

Comment: That didn't change the outcome. Thanks anyway.

Comment: At your picture the button position is center inside the window, the problem is the window is small, you can make it bigger with set `windowN.minSize=NSSize(width: 500, height: 100)` for example, or it's not work?

Comment: The window is supposed to be bigger but the window gets either smaller or bigger to make whatever location I have the button set to the center instead of moving it.

Comment: @B Person check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation:

> by default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints
>   that fully determine the view's position.  To do anything interesting
>   with constraints, you need to turn that off. IB will turn it off.

You need to turn off the autoresizing mask:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```